# How to create a docker file with Ballerina installed?

Tags: dockerfile, ballerina

I am doing a perf test. I already have a Docker file which consists of several other languages. I need to add ballerina for that file and create a docker image with ballerina 2201.5.0 installed on it. I have an Ubuntu base image.

I am using the below command to install java. What should be the command to install ballerina?

```
RUN apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
        openjdk-11-jre \
        openjdk-11-jdk
```

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/ballerina/ballerina

Answer (score 2):

Download the `DEB` package and install it using `dpkg`

```bash
ADD https://dist.ballerina.io/downloads/2201.5.0/ballerina-2201.5.0-swan-lake-linux-x64.deb ballerina.deb
RUN dpkg -i ballerina.deb
```

Reference: https://ballerina.io/downloads/installation-options/